# Format Kotlin String with multiple occurrences

Tags: string, kotlin

I've got a String template looking like this:

```
val template = "Something %s something else %s. The first was %1$s, the second was  %2$s"
```

works fine with Java. How do I use this reoccurring String values with Kotlin?
Looks like `%1$s` is not possible.

Compiler warning: `unresolved reference: s`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals in Kotlin are capable of string interpolation, and the dollar sign is the start of a [string template expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates). If you need the literal dollar sign in a string instead, you should escape it using a backslash: `\$`. So your template (which I assume you're passing to `String.format`) becomes:

```
val template = "Something %s something else %s. The first was %1\$s, the second was %2\$s"
```

Answer (score 5):

As [Alexander Udalov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33595713/6521116) say, `$` can be used for [String Templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates).

Apart from use backslash to escape the char `$`, you also can use `${'$'}` to escape it. This syntax will be more useful when you want to escape the `$` in a raw string, where backslash escaping is not supported.

```
val template = "Something %s something else %s. The first was %1${'$'}s, the second was %2${'$'}s"
```